# c# filesystemwatcher and backgroundworker

Tags: c#, backgroundworker, filesystemwatcher

I want so sync my Folder, so i have 10 Filesystemwatcher and 4 Backgroundworkers.
The idea is, that one watcher can call every of the 4 worker but i want that the watcher choose a active and free worker, the others should not be triggered.

Exp: worker 1 fired, 2-4 do not.

What am I doing wrong here?

Here is my Code

```
        private void watcher1_OnChanged(object source, FileSystemEventArgs e)
        {
            // File Name
            string file = e.FullPath;

            // refresh App.Config
            ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("appSettings");

            // Check Worker Active
            bool worker1Active = Convert.ToBoolean(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["worker1Active"]);
            bool worker2Active = Convert.ToBoolean(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["worker2Active"]);
            bool worker3Active = Convert.ToBoolean(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["worker3Active"]);
            bool worker4Active = Convert.ToBoolean(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["worker4Active"]);

            // Watcher Nummer
            string watcherNr = "Watcher 1";

            // Arguments to call worker
            List<object> arguments = new List<object>();
            arguments.Add(file);
            arguments.Add(watcher1_destinationPath);
            arguments.Add(watcher1_sourcePath);
            arguments.Add(watcherNr);

            bool success = false;

            while (!success == true)
            {
                try
                {
                    using (Stream stream = new FileStream(file, FileMode.Open))
                    {

                            if (worker1Active == true && worker1.IsBusy != true)
                            {
                                worker1.RunWorkerAsync(arguments);
                                success = true;
                                break;
                            }

                            if (worker2Active == true && worker2.IsBusy != true)
                            {
                                worker2.RunWorkerAsync(arguments);
                                success = true;
                                break;
                            }

                            if (worker3Active == true && worker3.IsBusy != true)
                            {
                                worker3.RunWorkerAsync(arguments);
                                success = true;
                                break;
                            }

                            if (worker4Active == true && worker4.IsBusy != true)
                            {
                                worker4.RunWorkerAsync(arguments);
                                success = true;
                                break;
                            }
                    }
                }
                catch
                {
                    success = false;
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Why are you not using thread pool?

Comment: What Aman said. This is not Thread safe. What do you do if all workers are busy and work is piling up?  You should use a Queue for queueing the work and a threadpool to pick up the work.  You let the filesystemwatcher queue the work for you and the threadpool can be set to a number of workers to do the work in the background.  If you want I can make a small example app and post the code here.

Comment: The real reason for threads is that you want to minimise the amount of work inside the event callback otherwise you run the risk of missing file system changes

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**EDIT:** Make sure to lock files during processing and check for a lock before processing. If you have multiple workers processing a single file you will run into problems. Just make sure you requeue the job when a file you want to process is locked. It will automatically requeue until it is unlocked. Ofcourse you need to take care of unlocking it again.

Here is an example app using the ThreadPool:
The ThreadPool is thread safe which means when it's doing it's work, it's doing it in different threads which will keep your UI responsive and not block.

Have fun!

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading;

namespace FileWatcherThreadApp
{
    class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            FileSystemWatcher fileWatcher = new FileSystemWatcher(@"C:\Users\BertSinnema\watch");

            //Enable events
            fileWatcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;

            //Add event watcher
            fileWatcher.Changed += FileWatcher_Changed;
            fileWatcher.Created += FileWatcher_Changed;
            fileWatcher.Deleted += FileWatcher_Changed;
            fileWatcher.Renamed += FileWatcher_Changed;

            var maxThreads = 4;

            // Times to as most machines have double the logic processers as cores
            ThreadPool.SetMaxThreads(maxThreads, maxThreads * 2);


            Console.WriteLine("Listening");
            Console.ReadLine();

        }

        //This event adds the work to the Thread queue
        private static void FileWatcher_Changed(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
        {
            ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem((o) => ProcessFile(e));
        }

        //This method processes your file, you can do your sync here
        private static void ProcessFile(FileSystemEventArgs e)
        {
            // Based on the eventtype you do your operation
            switch (e.ChangeType)
            {
                case WatcherChangeTypes.Changed:
                    Console.WriteLine($"File is changed: {e.Name}");
                    break;
                case WatcherChangeTypes.Created:
                    Console.WriteLine($"File is created: {e.Name}");
                    break;
                case WatcherChangeTypes.Deleted:
                    Console.WriteLine($"File is deleted: {e.Name}");
                    break;
                case WatcherChangeTypes.Renamed:
                    Console.WriteLine($"File is renamed: {e.Name}");
                    break;
            }
        }
    }


}
```

If you want to wach multiple folders, you can simply add another FileSystemWatcher and hook the Created, Renamed, Changed and Deleted events to the same eventhandler (FileWatcher_Changed)

Comment: Great. Thank you 1000 Times.

Comment: @Andre, please mark the answer if this is what you were looking for. It help's stackoverflow and myself. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should use ThreadPool. That will make your code look much clean and that is the thread mechanism you should use. It will put the task on one of the free threads and if all threads are busy then it will wait for one of the threads to be free.

Here is the link on how to use a ThreadPool in c#.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3dasc8as(v=vs.80).aspx
https://www.dotnetperls.com/threadpool

Also if you want to continue working with only four threads at a time you can set the maximum no. of thread in threads
[Here is how to do it.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadpool.setmaxthreads(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: that means i have one method ( worker ) and threadpool controls how many thread are parallel working. In this case how many Jobs are in Queue?!

Comment: @Andre you can have different worker methods.
There can be multiple threads running in parallel. If you want to run only one task use SerialWorkQueue. I have a sample code for it.
that will run everything in single thread and wait for one worker thread to be completed before going on to next one.

Comment: @Andre, check my answer. You can hook up multiple FilesystemWatchers to the eventhandler and simply queue the EventArgs class. Then in the ProcessFile method, which the worker runs,  you can call any other method based on the changetype